# getting last modified date for file in AppleScript

Tags: file, applescript, last-modified

I'm trying to get the last modified date for a file in AppleScript.  I thought I had this working using:

```
set thePath to (((path to documents folder) as text) & "speed.txt")
set modDate to modification date of file thePath
```

and this seemed to return a valid value but when I put this inside an `on idle` piece of the code I get an:

> "can't get class <> of..." error

I saw somewhere else a suggestion to use:

```
set the modDate to (do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemLasUsedDate " & quoted form of the POSIX path of thePath)
```

but this returns `null`.  Any ideas on how I can get the modified date?

Comment: does it have to be applescript ?  you can easily do this using stat filename

Comment: FYI: for your do shell script command there is a "kMDItemContentModificationDate" that would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reference the file.

Try

```
set thePath to (((path to documents folder) as text) & "speed.txt")
tell application "System Events" to set modDate to modification date of file thePath
```

or

```
tell application "System Events" to set thePath to file (((path to documents folder) as text) & "speed.txt")
set modDate to modification date of thePath
```

Comment: The only adjustment I would suggest is to tell application System Events instead of the Finder. In general it's always best to avoid using the Finder when possible. So seeing as both the Finder and System Events have the "modification date" property, I'd use the latter.

Comment: Also, I was surprised your second example worked because "modification date" is not a property that applescript knows. That property is known by the Finder and System Events so really you should be telling one of those applications to perform the command. I do see that when you create the file reference with one of those applications that at the end of the file reference it includes "of application Finder"... I'm guessing that's why the "modification date" call works outside the application tell block. Do you have a different explanation?

Comment: Hi regulus. System Events is faster and accepts posix paths as well so I will update the answer. (I have a script debugger expansion that populates Finder and I was being lazy.) I have found that once you reference a file in Finder or SE, you can exclude it from a tell block afterwards.

Comment: Interesting post. I noted that the script returns a string as follows:

    date "Wednesday, 12 August 2015 14:13:33"

I am assuming that this is language/region specific so how can it be converted to a known format in order to by parsed?